# How to go to matching pattern after org-occur?

Tags: org-mode, occur

After typing `C-c / /` and a regex, org shows a sparse tree containing matches of the pattern.

How do I move point through these matches, in a way similar to `C-s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command `next-error` that is bound to the key sequence <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> (the second char is a backtick).

As [Omar pointed out in his comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51003/how-to-go-to-matching-pattern-after-org-occur/51008?noredirect=1#comment78616_51008), there is also a global keymap for motion commands bound to <kbd>M-g</kbd>.
<kbd>M-g ?</kbd> gives the following listing:

```
Global Bindings Starting With M-g:  
key             binding  
---             -------  

M-g TAB     move-to-column  
M-g ESC     Prefix Command  
M-g c       goto-char  
M-g g       goto-line  
M-g n       next-error  
M-g p       previous-error  

M-g M-g     goto-line  
M-g M-n     next-error  
M-g M-p     previous-error
```

Note that <kbd>M-g n</kbd>, <kbd>M-g M-n</kbd> are bound to `next-error` and <kbd>M-g p</kbd>, <kbd>M-g M-p</kbd> to `previous-error` which is also working together with `org-occur`.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that `next-error` is also bound to `M-g M-n`. That binding has a companion for `previous-error`, namely `M-g M-p`.

Comment: @Omar Thanks. I was not aware of the `M-g` keymap. It is really precious!